# Is there a way to use ngx-spinner in standalone angular apps?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-spinner

How do I use ngx-spinner in my standalone angular app ?

There's no app.module to import it. I can't import it in the component itself because I get  "Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModule" error. And if I just declare it on constructor I get "'ngx-spinner' is not a known element" in the template.

How do I use it in standalone apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main.ts`, use the following:

```js
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(NgxSpinnerModule.forRoot(/*config*/)),
    provideAnimations()
  ]
});
```

What you set in the `providers` array is used the same as in the old `app.module.ts`'s imports (ie. it's declaring app-wide modules)

---

Edit on suggestion:

Remember to add the location of the CSS file in `angular.json` (`styles` array) and to import `NgxSpinner` in the components that use it.

Basically, follow [the docs](https://github.com/Napster2210/ngx-spinner#readme) except for the `providers` array in `bootstrapApplication(...)`

Comment: This answer is correct but it need some complementation. 

1. use importProvidersFrom(NgxSpinnerModule.forRoot(/* config */)) instead
2. put NgxSpinnerModule in the component
3. don't forget to put the correct css stylesheet in angular.json as stated in NgxSpinner documentation.

Comment: maybe it would be better to include the comment in the answer if you wish. In that case I'll remove the comment.

Comment: You're right. I edited the answer.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing you answer to include importProvidersFrom. If you didn't like it feel free to undo the changes.